# error while viewing the record

Tags: lightning

This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Unable to find action 'getAccountRecord' on the controller of c:ar2
Failing descriptor: {c:ar2}

```
public class ar2class {
@AuraEnabled
    public static List<Assets_Resources__c> getAssetRecord(){
        return new List<Assets_Resources__c> ([Select Name, Type_Of_Asset__c from Assets_Resources__c ]);
    }
}
```

---

```
<aura:component controller = "ar2class" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action = "{!c.doinit}" />
    <aura:attribute name="arlist" type="Assets_Resources__c[]" />
    <article class="slds-card">
      <div class="slds-card__header slds-grid">
        <header class="slds-media slds-media_center slds-has-flexi-truncate">
          <div class="slds-media__figure">
            <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-standard-account" title="description of icon when needed">
                <lightning:icon iconName="standard:account" size="large" alternativeText="List account"/>
            </span>
          </div>
            <div class="slds-media__body">
            <h2>
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-card__header-link slds-truncate" title="Asset and Resources">
                <span class="slds-text-heading_small">Asset and Resources</span>
              </a>
            </h2>
          </div>
        </header>
       </div>
        <div class="slds-card__body">
        <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-no-row-hover slds-table_cell-buffer">
            <thead>
            <tr class="slds-text-title_caps">
              <th scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Name">Name</div>
              </th>
              <th scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Type">Type of asset</div>
              </th>
              
            </tr>
          </thead>
            <tbody>
              <aura:iteration items="{!v.arlist}" var="ar"> <!-- iteration account record.-->
                  <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
                      <th scope="row">
                          <div class="slds-truncate" title="Adam Choi"><a href="javascript:void(0);">{!ar.Name}</a></div>
                      </th>
                      <td>
                          <div class="slds-truncate" title="Company One">{!ar.Type}</div>
                      </td>
                      
                  </tr>                     
              </aura:iteration>
          </tbody>
            </table>
      </div>
      <footer class="slds-card__footer"><a href="javascript:void(0);"><!--View All <span class="slds-assistive-text">entity type</span>--></a></footer>
    </article>
</aura:component>
```

---

```
({
    doinit : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.getAccontRecord(component);
    }
})
```

---

```
({
    getAccontRecord : function(component) {
        var action = component.get("c.getAccountRecord");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState(); //Checking response status
            var result = JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue());
            if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS")
                component.set("v.arlist", response.getReturnValue());  // Adding values in Aura attribute variable.   
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
                }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You named the method `getAssetRecord`, so that's what you should be calling, as in `component.get("c.getAssetRecord")`.